# How to parse the BigQuery response in android app?

Tags: android, json, parsing, google-bigquery

I am trying to access the database tables from Bigquery in Google developer console. The response is coming in following pattern:

```
[ 
    { "f": [ 
            { "v": "value1" }, 
            { "v": "value2" } 
          ]
    }, 
    { "f": [ 
            { "v": "value1" }, 
            { "v": "value2" } 
           ] 
    } 
]
```

It is long process to parse this and map to pojo class. So is there any other ways to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a JSON library would be your best bet... it at least takes away the headache of raw string parsing. As for pulling the items out, you'll still need to define a POJO to encapsulate the data if you want to use it easily.

Check out [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

Another one that's easy to use is the standard [JSON library](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html), but it is not as efficient.